# URL to package assets onTest for scrape testing

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am writing a meteor package which includes a scraper. Therefore, in my tinytest cases I need to ensure that a request to a web-resource is done correctly.

So I am adding a local asset (a html-file) which I hope to query while running a test via `localhost:3000/{magicpath}/dummywebsite.html`. I add the file in the package like so in the subfolder test/files/dummywebsite.html

```
Package.onTest(function(api) {
    api.use('tinytest');
    api.use('packageName');

    // test-assets - what is the URL to this asset during testing?
    api.addFiles(['test/files/dummywebsite.html'], ['client', 'server'], {isAsset: true});

    api.addFiles('test/packageName-tests.js', 'server');
});
```

I searched now for a while and tried different url-combinations to access the file while the tinytest html-reporter is running. There was a related meteor [github-issue discussion](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2580) regarding the use of static files from packages from the client side while onTesting... but I can not make sense of the outcome.

I tried:

```
http://localhost:3000/packages/author:packagename/test/files/dummywebsite.html
http://localhost:3000/packages/author_packagename/test/files/dummywebsite.html
http://localhost:3000/packages/local-test:author:packagename/assets/dummywebsite.html
```

But none yield any results :( Does some meteor ninja know how I can serve static html during testing?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @below9k, but my question discussed **how to access assets that where added during "onTest"**, not in general production use.

Meanwhile I found the answer. To access assets that are added for test cases in the onTest section a `local-test_` needs to be **suffixed** to the `author_package/` folder. See following sample package.js

```
// Write your package code here!
Package.describe({
  name: "author:package",
  summary: "A package to find the the url to the unknown depths of onTest static files in a meteor package.",
  version: "1.0.0"
});

Package.onUse(function (api, where) {
  api.versionsFrom('0.9.0');

  // Asset added during production
  // http://localhost:3000/packages/author_package/file/production.png
  // -> Works
    api.addFiles(['file/production.png'], ['client', 'server'], {isAsset: true});

  api.addFiles('test.js', ['client', 'server']);
});

Package.onTest(function(api) {
  api.use('author:package', ['client', 'server']);
  api.use(['tinytest', 'test-helpers'], ['client', 'server']);

  // Asset added onTest.
  // http://localhost:3000/packages/author_package/file/testing.png
  // -> Not available.
  // http://localhost:3000/packages/local-test_author_package/file/testing.png
  // -> Works, when "local-test_" is prefixed to the package name
    api.addFiles(['file/testing.png'], ['client', 'server'], {isAsset: true});

  // Asset added during production
  // http://localhost:3000/packages/author_package/file/production.png
  // -> Works

  api.addFiles('package-tests.js', ['client', 'server']);
});
```